# Android Room Multimap issue for the same column names

Tags: android-room, multimap

As stated in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#multimap), it's preferable to use the Multimap return type for the Android Room database.
With the next very simple example, it's not working correctly!

```
@Entity
data class User(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val _id: Long = 0, val name: String)

@Entity
data class Book(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val _id: Long = 0, val bookName: String, val userId: Long)
```

(I believe a loooot of the developers have the `_id` primary key in their tables)

Now, in the Dao class:

```
@Query(
    "SELECT * FROM user " +
        "JOIN book ON user._id = book.userId"
)
fun allUserBooks(): Flow<Map<User, List<Book>>>
```

The database tables:
[image]

[image]

**Finally, when I run the above query, here is what I get:**
[image]

While it should have 2 entries, as there are 2 users in the corresponding table.

PS. I'm using the latest Room version at this point, *Version 2.4.0-beta02*.

PPS. The issue is in how UserDao_Impl.java is being generated:
[image]

 all the `_id` columns have the same index there.

Is there a chance to do something here? (instead of switching to the intermediate data classes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> all the _id columns have the same index there.
> Is there a chance to do something here?

Yes, **use unique column names** e.g.

```
@Entity
data class User(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val userid: Long = 0, val name: String)

@Entity
data class Book(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) valbookid: Long = 0, val bookName: String, val useridmap: Long)
```

- as used in the example below.

or

```
@Entity
data class User(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name="userid")val _id: Long = 0, val name: String)

@Entity
data class Book(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name="bookid")val _id: Long = 0, val bookName: String, val @ColumnInfo(name="userid_map")userId: Long)
```

Otherwise, as you may have noticed, Room uses the value of the last found column with the duplicated name and the User's _id is the value of the Book's _id column.

Using the above and replicating your data using :-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getAllDao()

    var currentUserId = dao.insert(User(name = "Eugene"))
    dao.insert(Book(bookName = "Eugene's book #1", useridmap = currentUserId))
    dao.insert(Book(bookName = "Eugene's book #2", useridmap = currentUserId))
    dao.insert(Book(bookName = "Eugene's book #3", useridmap = currentUserId))
    currentUserId = dao.insert(User(name = "notEugene"))
    dao.insert(Book(bookName = "not Eugene's book #4", useridmap = currentUserId))
    dao.insert(Book(bookName = "not Eugene's book #5", useridmap = currentUserId))

    var mapping = dao.allUserBooks() //<<<<<<<<<< BREAKPOINT HERE
    for(m: Map.Entry<User,List<Book>> in mapping) {

    }
```

- for convenience and brevity a `Flow` hasn't been used and the above was run on the main thread.

Then the result is what I believe you are expecting :-

[image]

**Additional**

> What if we already have the database structure with a lot of "_id" fields?

Then you have some decisions to make.

You could

- do a migration to rename columns to avoid the ambiguous/duplicate column names.
- use alternative POJO's in conjunction with changing the extract output column names accordingly

e.g. have :-

```
data class Alt_User(val userId: Long, val name: String)
```

and

```
data class Alt_Book (val bookId: Long, val bookName: String, val user_id: Long)
```

along with :-

```
@Query("SELECT user._id AS userId, user.name, book._id AS bookId, bookName, user_id  " +
        "FROM user JOIN book ON user._id = book.user_id")
fun allUserBooksAlt(): Map<Alt_User, List<Alt_Book>>
```

- so user._id is output with the name as per the Alt_User POJO
- other columns output specifically (although you could use * as per allUserBookAlt2)

:-

```
@Query("SELECT *, user._id AS userId, book._id AS bookId " +
        "FROM user JOIN book ON user._id = book.user_id")
fun allUserBooksAlt2(): Map<Alt_User, List<Alt_Book>>
```

- same as allUserBooksAlt but also has the extra columns
- you would get a warning `warning: The query returns some columns [_id, _id] which are not used by any of [a.a.so70190116kotlinroomambiguouscolumnsfromdocs.Alt_User, a.a.so70190116kotlinroomambiguouscolumnsfromdocs.Alt_Book]. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping. You can annotate the method with @RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns to direct Room to rewrite your query to avoid fetching unused columns.  You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: _id, name, _id, bookName, user_id, userId, bookId. public abstract java.util.Map<a.a.so70190116kotlinroomambiguouscolumnsfromdocs.Alt_User, java.util.List<a.a.so70190116kotlinroomambiguouscolumnsfromdocs.Alt_Book>> allUserBooksAlt2();`

  - Due to *Note that Room will not rewrite the query if it has multiple columns that have the same name as it does not yet have a way to distinguish which one is necessary.* the [`@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns) doesn't do away with the warning.

if using :-

```
    var mapping = dao.allUserBooksAlt() //<<<<<<<<<< BREAKPOINT HERE
    for(m: Map.Entry<Alt_User,List<Alt_Book>> in mapping) {
    }
```

Would result in :-

[image]

- possibly other options.

However, I'd suggest fixing the issue once and for all by using a migration to rename columns to all have unique names. e.g.

Comment: Yeah, it does the trick, thanks.
However I was hoping that Room can do it somehow by its own means.

Comment: What if we already have the database structure with a lot of "_id" fields?

Comment: @GoltsevEugene updated the answer but probably not good news.

Comment: Got similar thoughts.
Thanks a lot and especially for that @Rewrite thing, might be helpful someday!

Comment: The issue has been fixed a few days ago. I suppose it should be available in a future version of Room.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201306012

Comment: I found that using column alias with @ColumnInfo is a cleaner solution so it will change only the database column name without poluting my kotling code. To keep using book.id instead of book.bookId

Comment: I use convention of always naming id as "id" on classes level, so I have properties like: MyEntitiy1.id, MyEntity2.id, ... but on tables level I name column to use entity name like: @ColumnInfo(name = "myentity1_id") ...